# JAVA POST API accepting multipart/form-data returns 400 response

Tags: javascript, java, http, post, postman

I have a Java API that is supposed to accept a list of files and then send them via email to users. The API is as follows:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/echoapi") 
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getNotificationByUser(@FormDataParam("name") String name, @FormDataParam("email") String email, @FormDataParam("file") InputStream file) {
        try {
            List<InputStream> attachments = new ArrayList<>();
            attachments.add(file);
            EmailUtils.sendEmail(name, email, attachments);
            
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson("");
            return Response.ok().entity(json).build();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            return Response.status(HttpStatus.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }

    }
```

When sending following request to this API using Postman (for testing purposes), I get a 400 response

headers:
[image]

body:
[image]

If I change the signature of the method to:

```
public Response getNotificationByUser(String requestBody)
```

everything works fine! I need however, to access the data within the API and not as a String so this is not sufficient